# Ruby: Is there a more eloquent way of iterating over items that can sometimes be a pair?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Sometimes I want to iterate over a collection. Each element is usually a pair.

```rb
{
  planet: { type: :rocky },
  planet: { type: :gaseous },
  planet: { type: :rocky, earth_like: :true }
}
```

In which case I can make use of the key and values.

However, sometimes there is no value. Like below:

```rb
{
  cat: {},
  dog: {},
  rat: {},
  elephant: { trunk_length: long },
  hedgehog: {},
}.each do |animal, options|
# ...
end
```

I end up with a load of empty hashes.

I could be more explicit:

```rb
{
  # ...
  { animal: :rat },
  { animal: :elephant, options: { trunk_length: :long } }
  # ...
}
```

Or use arrays instead:

```rb
[
  [:cat],
  [:dog],
  [:rat],
  [:elephant, { trunk_length: :long }],
  [:hedgehog]
].each do |animal|
  # ...
end
```

But I don't think it's any different to having empty hashes. There's still the need to add an extra object. In the latter case, I have to wrap single elements in an array.

Is there a more eloquent way to do this *without* creating a custom class?

Comment: What do you mean as pair? Maybe key/value? What’s te problem with empty Hash as value? Can you provide a representative input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

One might not use arrays when they are not needed and use whenever required.

```
input = [:cat, [:elephant, trunk_length: :long]]
#⇒ [:cat, [:elephant, {:trunk_length=>:long}]]

input.each do |animal|
  case animal
  when Symbol then puts "#{animal} has no properties"
  when Array 
    puts "#{animal.first} has properties #{animal[1..-1].inspect}"
  else
    puts "Unknown animal in the input #{animal.inspect}"
  end
end
#⇒ cat has no properties
#  elephant has properties [{:trunk_length=>:long}]
```

Comment: Type-switching, not very OOP-ish :) But OP did specifically ask not to use classes.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev in 2.7 ⇑ should become a charm with pattern matching :)